# XPATH - How can I select the node which has a child node with a given attribute with the maximum value?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

For example:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>c1 text</b1>
    <c2 c2attr="10">c2 text</b2>
    <c3>c3 text</b3>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c1>c1 text</b1>
    <c2 c2attr="5">c2 text</b2>
    <c3>c3 text</b3>
  </b>
</a>
```

I want to select the `<b>` element which has a `<c2>` child with the maximum `c2attr` attribute; in this example, the first one (10 > 5).

I have tried

```
/a/b[not(c2@c2attr <= preceding-sibling::c2@c2attr) and not(c2@c2attr <=following-sibling::c2@c2attr)]
```

But PHP says that it's invalid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing slashes before the `@` signs, and you need to look for `preceding-sibling` elements named `b`, not `c2`:

```
/a/b[not(c2/@c2attr <= preceding-sibling::b/c2/@c2attr) and not(c2/@c2attr <=following-sibling::b/c2/@c2attr)]
```

However this kind of check will be quadratic in the number of `b` elements, as it's comparing every `b` with every other `b`.  It would be more efficient to simply extract all the `b` elements, then iterate over them (once) using PHP code, keeping track of the highest `c2attr` value you've seen so far and which `b` that belongs to.  This would be linear rather than quadratic.